# Crop UIImage in UIScrollView like in "Move And Scale"

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

How to create custom "Move and scale" view as in UIImagePickerController? I need move and scale my custom UIImages, not from Photo library. 
Or maybe there is way to pass UIImage to this view?
[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do. I imagine others feel the same, that is why no one has commented on this yet.

Comment: "I need move and scale my custom UIImages, not from Photo library" what is difficult here?)

Comment: This is what I mean. What does 'move' mean? Scale I understand. You have a UIImage in one size, you want to scale it I suppose to a smaller size?

Comment: It means you can move Squared rectangle to crop selected image. Look at screeenshot

Comment: Great, we're slowly making progress! So the slightly brighter square is the crop. We extra that no problem. But you save move it. That is what is confusing. So when user tap Choose, then the big image is just going to be replaced with the smaller crop, and will appear in the top of the view. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question. Solved this problem with good [example](http://codefuel.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/image-cropping-from-a-uiscrollview/). Hope someone it will help

Comment: How do you get the position of the cropRectangle ? I'm facing exactly the same problem but the solution in the link get the full image in the scrollview not what is inside the crop square

Comment: Look at that example, that I've posted. It's calculating selected frame. Download that code at github

Comment: sorry but probably I'm missing something the code you linked get what is visible on screen inside the scrollView, What I miss is how do u use that code to crop only part of the visible content

Comment: Download this project: https://github.com/ArjunNair/ImageCroppingExample
And you will understand it

Comment: ok Probably we are trying to achieve two differents objectives. In my case on top of the scrollView there is another view (cropView) like the picture you posted I would like to crop the part that is visible on the cropView, and not what is visible in the scrollView.