# Draw the zoomed & panned portion of a UIScrollview as a new UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage

I would like to draw a thumbnail of a UIScrollview.

This scrollview has an image in. However the user can zoom and pan the image.

When the user has panned and zoomed to where he wants the picture, I want to create a thumbnail of what they set up. Basically, I want to create a brand new uiimage that is sized at say 100x100, but uses the exact image data that the scrollview is currently showing.

I tried this, but the more I zoom in, the more distorted the images became.

```
 //returns a smaller UIImage
    func generateThumbnailOfSize(size:CGSize)->UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_scrollView.bounds.size)
        _scrollView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        var fullsizeCroppedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), fullsizeCroppedImage.CGImage)
        var sizeAdjustedCroppedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()//gets the image as it looks in the scrollview
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return sizeAdjustedCroppedImage
    }
```

Suggestions?:)
Swift & Objc code welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at this:

[Crop UIImage in UIScrollView like in "Move And Scale"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669596/crop-uiimage-in-uiscrollview-like-in-move-and-scale)

In case anyone is interested in more sophisticated solution:

https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper